# updating a label with a changing variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a clock app using tkinter, and i used the datetime
module to get the current system time, and i made a function to update
a label to the current time.

clock_label is a tk.Label and it will be updated to the current system time every 80 milliseconds, like this;

```
import tkinter
import datetime
from time import strftime

...

window = tk.Tk()
clock_label = tk.Label(window)
clock_label.grid()


def update_label():

   time = datetime.today().strftime("%I:%M:%S%p")   # current system time
   config_label()

   clock_label.config(text=time)

   clock_label.after(80, lambda: update_clock()) 

update_label()
window.mainloop()
```

And...

I made a function where the user can change the timezone,

> with the help of pytz, tzlocal and timezone modules i was able to get
> the current time from any selected timezone,
>
> for example if the user selected Europe/madrid the function will
> return the current time of that timezone; (i assigned it as a
> variable: new_time)

the problem i have is that i'm not sure how to update the clock_label with the new time;

```
 selected_timezone_name = "Europe/Madrid"
 
 ...  # code for getting the time from a selected timezone

 new_time = datetime.strftime(selected_time_object, "%H:%M:%S")
 # update the clock_label with new time
```

> beacuse the new_time variable keeps changing i need to make a function
> which keeps updating the clock_label with the new_time,
>
> I tried to make function which updates the clock_label with the new
> time similar to update label() but beacuse the update_label() function
> keeps updating the clock_label with the system time it creates
> confusion

Answer (score 1):

i edited the above code a little. let me know if it helps solve your problem

```
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
from time import strftime
import pytz

window = tk.Tk()
clock_label = tk.Label(window)
clock_label.pack()

selected_place = tk.Label(window)
selected_place.pack()


def update_label():
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%I:%M:%S:%p")   # current system time

    timeZ_At = pytz.timezone('Europe/Athens')  # europe timezone
    dt_At = datetime.datetime.now(timeZ_At)
    Europe_time = dt_At.strftime("%I:%M:%S:%p")

    clock_label.config(text=time)  
    selected_place.config(text = Europe_time)

    clock_label.after(80, lambda: update_label()) 

update_label()
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Now for the issue, can the timezone be passed as a parameter to the update_label function?

Something like this:

```
def update_label(tz = 'US/Pacific'):
  time = datetime.datetime.now(timezone(tz)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  clock_label.config(text=time)
  clock_label.after(80, lambda: update_clock())
```

Comment: For this to work, you need to pass the timezone when calling `update_clock` from `after`.

Comment: I got an error: 'TypeError: timezone() argument 1 must be datetime.timedelta, not str',

Comment: should I pass a string as tz argument or another type?

Comment: Sorry! It should be timezone.gettz(tz)

Comment: I tried but I got another error: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.timezone' has no attribute 'gettz', :(

Comment: I tried but I got another error: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.timezone' has no attribute 'gettz', :( –

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer! gettz can be called from dateutil, so install it with pip and import it to your script `from dateutil import tz`